# How to move part of torrent in rtorrent?

Tags: rtorrent

Searching for "move" and "rtorrent" only leads to questions about completed torrents. I'm interested in moving a single file that is part of a larger torrent to a different directory.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can make a hardlink to it if the directory is on the same filesystem (`ln your/file other/dir`). But the file will be garbage before it is fully downloaded (torrent segments are not downloaded sequentially, and even a file that's 99% may be completely unusable, but you probably already know that)

Comment: I want to clear up the directory that file is staying in. Since it is less important I want to move it off into a subdirectory. I asked the question about one file, since I assume the method would be similar if it was a thousand files instead. I'm migrating from azureus 4.X where it was a simple act of right clicking a file and then selecting what I wanted to do. Like renaming or moving.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *move* part of a torrent to a different directory without breaking the Download/Seeding process, but you can *copy* an individual file of an existing torrent to a different directory while the torrent is continuing to Download/Seed.

Having said that, you could *try*:

- stopping the torrent
- move the file to another directory
- creating a symlink in the torrent's file directory to the new location
- resume the torrent

<sub>**Note:** *Try* as it should theoretically work, but I'm not currently torrenting anything right now so cannot test...</sub>

Comment: It's not about space, I want that file to disappear from the directory it's in. After your method I'd still be left with a symlink.

Comment: I could do it without problems in azureus/vuze 4.X, so it's definitely possible. Worst case I can't migrate over, since this is one of those basic features I'm heavily reliant on.

Comment: It's not missing. It's just moved to a different directory and seeded from there. As long as my client knows where the file is everything works fine. I move files I seed to different directories for most of my torrents and have trouble understanding why rtorrent shouldn't be able to accomplish that just fine. Can you at least rename files with rtorrent?

Comment: Well, then we've come full circle: use the symlink option: that uses just a few bytes of storage. (all other comments deleted)

Comment: The point isn't to save storage, the point is to reduce clutter by moving unneeded files. Imagine a directory with 2000 files. I want to move 1950 files away, so it's easier to see the relevant 50 files. In vuze I would have selected the 1950 files, right clicked and then clicked on move from the menu. After that the files were moved to a different directory while still being downloaded/seeded.